# Want to open a folder window in certain size and location, is possible

Tags: java

I'm trying to use Java for opening folder windows in a certain location on my screen. I want to adjust their size, so I tried using the `Desktop` class, and the `open()` method, but it wont let me set location or size. Any ideas?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis What keeps the OP from using a library to send Windows messages to the application requesting movement or resizing of the window?

Comment: @hexafraction Lack of knowledge of such a library.

Comment: The window you see is the `explorer.exe` process. AFAIK You cannot modify that application's settings, through Java.

Comment: what kind of OS?! I think you need to get help of native guys, this is possible with many OS APIs.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It should be possible with JNI-wrapping/loading win32.dll and/or win32k.dll.

Comment: @hexafraction I don't think that would be enough. You would need to get the process' id and, if it responds to such commands, write to its standard input commands to move/resize.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Why standard input? This is handling window events which AFAICT Windows API can do sufficiently with a spoonful of JNI.

Comment: @hexafraction Doesn't `Desktop#open(File)` launch a new Process. Does Windows' event handling system notify all `explorer` processes?

Comment: The OS is windows xp, and if someone can provide a short code or something, ill try to google and learn more about it!

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis No, event handling can refer to a single window. It is the method the OS and other processes notify target processes of mouse, window resizing, and close-requested events(among others) with a target window in mind.